# How to change the style of the hover text generated by tags$i?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinyapps

I am looking for a way to change the layout (such as font, background colour, etc.) of the hover text ("title") generated by `tags$i`. The style argument applies only to the icon generated, not the title appearing upon hover. I found several options using `shinyBS` but, unfortunately, I am restricted to `tags$i`.

Here's a small example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("Input", 
                label = tags$span(
                  "Input", 
                  tags$i(
                    class = "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign",
                    style = "color: black",
                    title = "hover text"
                  ),
                ),
                choices = c("a","b")),
    ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility without using `shinyBS`: Add the info sign as a separate `div` and add the corresponding `HTML` and `CSS` separately. Then you can fully customise the displayed text when hovering the info sign.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        tags$head(tags$style(
            HTML(
                "
      #info-sign {
      margin-left:40px;
      margin-top:3px;
      position: absolute;
      }

      #info-sign .text {
      position:absolute;
      bottom:-5px;
      left:20px;
      visibility:hidden;
      font-weight:bolder;
      }

      #info-sign:hover .text {
      visibility:visible;
      color:red;
      }
      "
            )
        )),
        
        selectInput(
            "Input",
            label = tags$span("Input"),
            choices = c("a", "b")
        ),
        
        # HTML for the info sign
        tags$div(
            id = 'info-sign',
            class = "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign",
            tags$span(class = "text", tags$p("formatted"))
        )
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output) {
        
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! How can I make the hover text box look nice for larger texts? By default, it looks cut off.

Comment: "look nice" is very relative. Have a look at `CSS`, there are a plenty of options for designing such elements. For example, if you insert `background-color: yellow; width: 300px;` to the `#info-sign:hover .text` given in my example, then you create a yellow background which has a larger width then the default. You could add a `height` and so on ...

Comment: Hi Jan, yes, I got that far, but I struggled to adjust the stacking order to avoid larger hover texts being placed under the input box. I think I found the right setting now with z-index. Thanks again for your help; I realise a picture might have helped clarify better my second query.